# CSS question: Flexible width to make it reflow ready

Tags: css, reflow

Could anyone please help me with this, How can I make the parent container flexible and make it reflow ready?

```css
.container{
width: 350px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.item{
margin-top:2px;
display: flex;
}

.line{
flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>xyx</span></div>
  <span>10 USD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>q</span></div>
  <span>* 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>total</span></div>
  <span>20 USD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what reflow are referring are you referring to? is it being responsive when the browser change its width?

Comment: Correct, when i change browser window size to minimum (320 * 340)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are referring reflow as **browser width change** and your default width for the container is **350px**

just your change `width: 350px` to `max-width: 350px`. Your container is now responsive for smaller browser width

You can play around around here and change the browser here:

```css
.container{
max-width: 350px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.item{
margin-top:2px;
display: flex;
}

.line{
flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>xyx</span></div>
  <span>10 USD</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>q</span></div>
  <span>* 2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
  <div class="line"><span>total</span></div>
  <span>20 USD</span>
  </div>
</div>
```